# saving R leaflet map as html will not open in excel 2010 windows web browser activex control

Tags: r, excel, leaflet, webbrowser-control

I would like to open an interactive map produced in R leaflet and saved as standalone HTML file (R HTML widget) within excel 2010 using the windows web browser active control.  I am able to open a web page e.g. google, a simple text title HTML document but the map file will not display.  It does display outside of excel using IE 11 (once I disabled compatibility mode).  The vba for opening the file is using navigate.

```
[error 2 window][1]
[error 1 window][2]
[error 3 window][3]
```

Any help would be appreciated.